# Find the differential equation which has a general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: Find the differential equation which has a general solution: $y = {1 \over 12}(C_1+x)^4 + xC_2 + C_3$

My approach:

First differentiation: $y'={1 \over 3}(C_1+x)^3+C_2$

Second differentiation: $y''=(C_1+x)^2$

Third differentiation: $y'''=2(C_1+x)$

Forth differentiation: $y''''=2$

I can express $C_1={y''' \over 2}-x$ or $C_1=\sqrt{y''}-x$

From here I can express $C_2=y'-{1 \over 3}(C_1+x)^3=y'-{1 \over 3}({y''' \over 2})^3$ or $C_2=y'-{1 \over 3}(C_1+x)^3=y'-{1 \over 3}(\sqrt{y''})^3$

How do I find $C_3$ or am I missing something in the picture?

Comment: Your DE $y''''=2$ has more solutions than the ones specified.  Perhaps this is it ... $(y''')^2=48y''$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to express $C_1, C_2,$ and $C_3$ in terms of $y$ and its derivatives in order to solve the problem. Just eliminate $C_1+x$ from the equations
\begin{align}
y''&=(C_1+x)^2, \tag{1} \\
y'''&=2(C_1+x), \tag{2}
\end{align}
to obtain
$$
(y''')^2=4y''. \tag{3}
$$